# django-admin formfield is missing on the admin form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I've got a very strange problem. I deployed my project from my development PC (manage.py runserver) to my webserver (apache mod_wsgi), created my database tables and logged in to django-admin.

I can see my models which are registered to the admin and I can add them. Two of my models do not have all the formfields they should have. A selectbox for a FK-field is missing. The label for this field is available but the field itself is missing.

A JS-error is not the problem because the field is also missing when JS is not active. So I think that the field isn't rendered yet.

There are no error-messages or anything else that could help me to fix the problem.

Anyone ever had the same problem or some Ideas about how to fix this problem? Here is my code:

```
class Heft(models.Model):
  doi = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=u"pdf")
  cover = models.FileField(upload_to=u"cover")
  xhtml = models.FileField(upload_to=u"xhtml", blank=True, null=True,)
  heftnr = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u"Nr.")
  offset = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  ivzende = models.IntegerField()
  ivzstart = models.IntegerField()
  jahrgang = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u"Jahrgang")
  pubdatum = models.IntegerField()
  copyname = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u"Copyright Name")
  copyyear = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u"Copyright Jahr")
  startseite = models.IntegerField()
  erschdatum = models.DateField()
  zeitschrift = models.ForeignKey(u"Zeitschrift", verbose_name="Zeitschrift") # !!!! THIS FIELD IS MISSING AT THE FORM !!!!
  sachgebiete = models.ManyToManyField(u"Sachgebiet")

class HeftAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [AbstractHeftInlineAdmin, ]
  actions = None
  save_on_top = True
  list_display = (u"getFullName", u"heftnr",u"jahrgang", u"hasPDF",u"artikelCnt",
                  u"bearbeiten", u"showArtikel", u"splitPDF", u"exportHeft",
                  u"getExportPackage",)
  search_fields = (u"zeitschrift__zsname", u"heftnr", u"jahrgang",)
  filter_horizontal = (u"sachgebiete", )
  list_display_links = (u"getFullName", u"bearbeiten", )

  fieldsets = [
    (u"Allgemeine Informationen", {u"fields": [u"zeitschrift", u"heftnr",
                                               u"jahrgang", u"erschdatum",
                                               u"pubdatum", u"copyname",
                                               u"copyyear", u"sachgebiete",
                                               u"doi", u"cover", u"pdf",
                                               u"xhtml" ]}),
    (u"Herstellungsangaben", {u"fields": [u"ivzstart", u"ivzende",
                                          u"startseite", u"offset", ]}),
  ]
```

kind regards
Martin

Comment: Does Apache serve your static files properly?

Comment: I think it does but why are the staticfiles are important in this case? The form isn't rendered out of static files, is it?

Comment: the widget used to render the field might use static files

Comment: I checked how apache serves the static files and I think it's ok.
Verry confusing: some FK-field widgets are sown and one is not.

Comment: check the html for this field, is there nothing there? or there is?

Comment: the source of the page shows nothing where the selectbox should be. The label for the formfield is available but the formfield itself is not.

Comment: please add to your post all related models (and other useful code you have realted..). because I tested this on my machine and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have the solution for this problem (but no explanation).

I killed all the database tables belonging to my project and recreated them ... magic ... everything works fine.

Maybe before some constraints were missing or something like this?

Comment: check if it related to the number of items. I think this is the reason (try add only 5 and than 30,000 and see if there is a difference)

Comment: related to the number of items? There were no Items in the database when I started and the field isn't shown. When I create a dataset which can be related the field also wasn't shown.

I think the FK constraint wasn't set correctly the first time and when I cleaned up the database and regenerated the tables again it was correct